# Array not changing Value java

Tags: java, arrays

Hello how do i change the value of an index in an char array? i tried the usual way array[][] = "";
but when i print it it still displays the original hard coded array.

this is the main

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
    int seatChoice = 0,seatCol = 0; 
    String seat, type;
    char[][]  airplane = {{'*','*','*','*','*','*'},{'*','*','*','*','*','*'},{'*','*','*','*','*','*'},
                        {'*','*','*','*','*','*'},{'*','*','*','*','*','*'},{'*','*','*','*','*','*'},
                        {'*','*','*','*','*','*'},{'*','*','*','*','*','*'},{'*','*','*','*','*','*'},
                        {'*','*','*','*','*','*'},{'*','*','*','*','*','*'},{'*','*','*','*','*','*'},
                        {'*','*','*','*','*','*'}};
    menu(airplane);
    System.out.print("Please input ticket type: ");
    type = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please input desired seat: ");
    seat = input.nextLine();
    seatChoice =  reservation(seat) - 1;
    if(seat.charAt(1) == 'A')
        seatCol = 0;
    if(seat.charAt(1) == 'B')
        seatCol = 1;
    if(seat.charAt(1) == 'C')
        seatCol = 2;
    if(seat.charAt(1) == 'D')
        seatCol = 3;
    if(seat.charAt(1) == 'E')
        seatCol = 4;
    if(seat.charAt(1) == 'F')
        seatCol = 5;
    airplane[seatChoice][seatCol] = 'X';

    System.out.println(seatChoice);
    System.out.println(seatCol);
    System.out.println(airplane[seatChoice][seatCol]);
    showSeat(airplane);
}
```

these are the other methods

```
   public static int reservation(String seat){
    int seatChoice = 0;
    seatChoice = Character.getNumericValue(seat.charAt(0));
    System.out.println("Your seat has been reserved.");
    return seatChoice;
}
public static void showSeat(char[][] airplane){
    int rows = 13, seats = 6, numRow = 1;
    System.out.println("         A  B  C  D  E  F ");
    System.out.println();
    for (int count = 0; count < rows; count++){
        System.out.print("ROW " + numRow + "    ");
        for (int count2 = 0; count2 < seats; count2++){
            System.out.print(" " + airplane[rows-1][seats-1] + " ");
        }
        numRow++;
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not what you asked, but those 6 Ifs in a row could be replaced by seatCol = Character.getNumericValue(seat.charAt(1)) - Character.getNumericValue('A');

Answer (score 2):

The value of `rows` and `seats` in

```
System.out.print(" " + airplane[rows-1][seats-1] + " ");
```

is not changing, they are always based upon `int rows = 13, seats = 6,`

try using `count` and `count2`